# Git: Where are my cherry-pick commits in bitbucket web page?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I needed to create a branch for a patch in our development. In that branch I had to  execute "git cherry-pick xxxxx" on three commits because I needed to include them in the branch. But when I go to the bitbucket web page and click on the Commits button, I see my branch but where are my cherry picked commits?

I see them when I do "git log". 
The reason I ask this is because one of the commits that I cherry picked has a tag associated to it, and I do not see it in bitbucket.

Comment: Did you `git push --tags`?

Comment: Thanks @RomainValeri, but what does this do? Is there anything else that needs to be executed on the patch branch after cherry picking? I also do not see my cherry picked commits.

Comment: I should have asked the more basic question before, sorry : did you push anything to the remote? after you cherry-picked? If not, your remote branch is just not up-to-date with local.

Comment: No I didn't push. I just did a "git push" and now I see my cherry picked commits. But one of the commits has a tag which I do not see on the remote. Do I do a separate "git push --tags"?

Comment: Yes, it'll then send the tag refs and you'll be set on remote. I've turned these comments into an answer to reap the humongous reputation bonus associated ! ;-)

Comment: Done! Thanks for your help. I marked it as my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just push your commits then your tags :

```
git push
git push --tags
```

to reflect on the remote what you have in your local environment.